# HTML ng-controller vs app.controller() formats inconsistent

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to define controllers in HTML and js using a very simple example. Ken's controller works. Barbies doesnt. why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/laurencefass/b18w58kc/1/

```
 <div ng-app='demo'>
  <p ng-controller='MyCtrl'>Hi, it's Ken. The current time is {{ken_time}}</p>
  <p>Hi, it's Barbie. The current time is {{barbie_time}}</p>
```

angular code

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.ken_time = new Date().toTimeString();
}

app.controller('BarbieCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.barbie_time = new Date().toTimeString();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wire the controller : add `ng-controller='BarbieCtrl'`

```
<div ng-app='demo'>
  <p ng-controller='MyCtrl'>Hi, it's Ken. The current time is {{ken_time}}</p>
  <p ng-controller='BarbieCtrl'>Hi, it's Barbie. The current time is {{barbie_time}}</p>
</div>
```

Also, you need to add the controller to the correct app : `demo.controller` instead of `app.controller`

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.ken_time = new Date().toTimeString();
}

demo.controller('BarbieCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.barbie_time = new Date().toTimeString();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `demo` and using it as `app`.

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
    ^^^  -->//defined
```

Used:

```
app.controller('BarbieCtrl', function($scope) {
^^^ --> //app is undefined
```

> **Note**: `ng-controller` is required when wiring controller.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b18w58kc/3/)

Complete snippet:

```
<div ng-app='demo'>
    <p ng-controller='MyCtrl'>Hi, it's Ken. The current time is {{ken_time}}</p>
    <p ng-controller='BarbieCtrl'>Hi, it's Barbie. The current time is {{barbie_time}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. Brought to you by ninja edits, but hence the most complete answer anyhow ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing `app.controller`, instead of `demo.controller`.

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.ken_time = new Date().toTimeString();
}

demo.controller('BarbieCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.barbie_time = new Date().toTimeString();
});
```

Futhermore, you'll need to define a controller for your Barbie Time:

```
<p ng-controller='BarbieCtrl'>Hi, it's Barbie. The current time is {{barbie_time}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let try to explain what is not working here.

1. In your html you have defined app as demo and the controller you are using for `barbie_time` is associated with app. and there is not app module either.
2. Also MyCtrl is an independent controller which is not associated with any module. Not with demo also.

To make it working you have to bind you controller with `demo` module and need to attach controller using `ng-controller` directive like below

```
      <div ng-app='demo'>
      <p ng-controller='MyCtrl'>Hi, it's Ken. The current time is  {{ken_time}}</p>
      <p ng-controller="BarbieCtrl">Hi, it's Barbie. The current time is {{barbie_time}}</p>


      var demo = angular.module('demo', []);

      function MyCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.ken_time = new Date().toTimeString();
      }

      demo.controller('BarbieCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.barbie_time = new Date().toTimeString();
      });
```

See your working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b18w58kc/5/
Newbie get confused with word `app` because it is very common for defining module in angular. `app` is no keyword in AngularJS to work like module, you have to define one to work like module. Hope this helps to you.